# Apply [FromBody] attribute to all controller actions in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, modelbinders

Having a simple .NET Core API with your models posted as JSON in request body, how to have `[FromBody]` attribute applied to all controller methods?

```
[Route("api/simple")]
public class SimpleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] MyRequest request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

If I remove the `[FromBody]` attribute, all model properties will be null.

Answer (score 5):

If you `POST` your model inside the body with `Content-Type: application/json` then you **[have to](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)** tell the `ModelBinder` to read the model from body by applying `[FromBody]` attribute.

But adding `[FromBody]` to all of your API actions makes you feel bad.

Just apply the [[ApiController]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#apicontroller-attribute) to your controller and then you don't need `[FromBody]` anymore.

Microsoft Doc definition of `[ApiController]`

> Indicates that a type and all derived types are used to serve HTTP API responses.
>
> Controllers decorated with this attribute are configured with features and behavior targeted at improving the developer experience for building APIs.

So this works without [FromBody] in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and above

```
[Route("api/simple")]
[ApiController]
public class SimpleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(OrderRequest request)
    {
         return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of options for applying the attribute; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#apicontroller-attribute
I found `[assembly: ApiController]` when converting a large .net framework project to .net